# How to customize only arrow of <select> dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, xhtml

This is code of  dropdown

```
<select id="dropdown">
                <option value="">Go to page...</option>
                <option value="http://stackoverflow.com">CSS-Tricks</option>
                <option value="http://superuser.com">Digging Into WordPress</option>
                <option value="http://metastackoverflow.com">Quotes on Design</option>
            </select>
```

I just want to customize arrow image background and border? I know many jquery and moo tools plugins but i want light and simple and customizable jquery way?

[alt text http://easycaptures.com/fs/uploaded/226/6042718975.png](http://easycaptures.com/fs/uploaded/226/6042718975.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not possible to just style that.  I wrote selectzor a while back to meet these needs though.  Check it out below.

http://jeremy.infinicastonline.com/2010/01/selectzor/

Comment: i just have a one dropdown on whole site. is it worth to use ur solution for just one dropdown. and ur solution as u mentioned not compatible with IE 6 which i need also. but i liked ur solution .

Comment: can u make ur selectzor.js more tiny for just one dropdown. i don't need functionality of Sample 2 which is in ur example file

Answer (score 0):

Drop-downs are rendered by the OPERATING SYSTEM, not the BROWSER. You have no control over this other than to roll-your-own.

Answer (score 0):

You can’t style it with jQuery either. jQuery isn’t a magic wand that lets you do anything you can imagine to a web page.

Generally, your options for styling form controls are going to be quite limited, because:

1. It’d be complicated for browser makers to let form controls be styleable; and
2. It’s actually good that form controls always look the same. It means that users know what they are, and thus what’ll happen when they click on them.

Comment: 1. Seems not to 'complicated' for other form elements. It was just never part of the HTML spec.

Comment: “Seems not to 'complicated' for other form elements.” Ah, you’ve clearly never tried to style an HTML checkbox. http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2007/05/15/formal-weirdness/

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative made by me. Might help.

[Codepen example](http://codepen.io/Dragosb/pen/Pbpvzy)

```
<div class="credit-mob-rate">
  <fieldset>
      <select id="timeframe-select" class="timeframe" tabindex="-1">
        <option value="1" selected="">1 an</option>
        <option value="2">2 ani</option>
        <option value="3">3 ani</option>
        <option value="4">4 ani</option>
        <option value="5">5 ani</option>
      </select>
      <span class="ion-arrow-down-b"></span>
   </fieldset>
</div>
```

And js for different events. You will find the css there.

```
$("#timeframe-select").blur(function() {
    console.log('blur');
    $('.credit-mob-rate').removeClass('highlight-mobile');
    $('.credit-mob-rate fieldset span').addClass("ion-arrow-down-b");
    $('.credit-mob-rate fieldset span').removeClass("ion-arrow-up-b");
});

$("#timeframe-select").change(function() {
    if ($('.credit-mob-rate fieldset span').hasClass('ion-arrow-up-b')) {
        this.selectChanged = true;
    }
    console.log('change');
    $('.credit-mob-rate fieldset span').addClass("ion-arrow-down-b");
    $('.credit-mob-rate fieldset span').removeClass("ion-arrow-up-b");
});

$("#timeframe-select").click(function() {
    console.log('click');
    if (this.selectChanged) {
        this.selectChanged = false;
        return;
    }

    if ($('.credit-mob-rate fieldset span').hasClass('ion-arrow-up-b')) {

        $('.credit-mob-rate fieldset span').addClass("ion-arrow-down-b");
        $('.credit-mob-rate fieldset span').removeClass("ion-arrow-up-b");
    } else {
        $('.credit-mob-rate fieldset span').addClass("ion-arrow-up-b");
        $('.credit-mob-rate fieldset span').removeClass("ion-arrow-down-b");
    }
    $('.credit-mob-rate').addClass('highlight-mobile');
});

$("#timeframe-select").on('keypress', function(e) {
    if (e.charCode != 13 && e.charCode != 10) {
        return;
    }
    console.log('keypress');
    if (this.selectChanged) {
        this.selectChanged = false;
        $('.credit-mob-rate').addClass('highlight-mobile');
        $('.credit-mob-rate fieldset span').addClass("ion-arrow-down-b");
        $('.credit-mob-rate fieldset span').removeClass("ion-arrow-up-b");

    } else {
        $('.credit-mob-rate').addClass('highlight-mobile');
        $('.credit-mob-rate fieldset span').addClass("ion-arrow-up-b");
        $('.credit-mob-rate fieldset span').removeClass("ion-arrow-down-b");
    }
});
```